# SharePoint 2010: List Name Change Caused listdata.svc Error

Tags: list, sharepoint, odata

I am using a list on SharePoint 2010 to feed data into Excel via OData. It worked fine under the old list name of "FM Utilities" as https://portal2010.xxxxxx.com/sites/fmvendors/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/FMUtilities (etc).

I changed the list name to "3 FM Utilities", and now the href in listdata.svc is "c_3FMUtilities". I am fine with that, but when I try to go to https://portal2010.xxxxxx.com/sites/fmvendors/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/c_3FMUtilities, I get an error message that Internet Explorer cannot display this feed, and the error below states "The following tags were not closed: feed."

I've tried to edit the feed name in both the browser and SharePoint Designer, but I still have the same problem. I have looked for a solution, but I can't find one. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Alex

Comment: Sounds like IE is failing to parse the feed correctly. What happens if you turn off feed reading view in Internet Explorer (Internet Options -> Content -> Feeds and Web Slices -> Settings -> Advanced -> Turn on feed reading view) and re-navigate to the URL? Will it display the raw XML, or does it still give you an error?

Comment: This is what was returned when I tried that:
The XML page cannot be displayed Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the  Refresh button, or try again later. The following tags were not closed: feed. Error processing resource 'https://portal2010.xxxxxx.com/sites/fmvendors/_vti_bin...